# Adding markers at intervals to videoview player in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, marker

Is it possible to add markers to video's at regular intervals on the video view progress bar so that the video can stop at that point and start another activity? For instance at 10 min into a video I need a marker in the videoview progress bar, and when the video comes to 10 min, the video stops and the other activity starts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, It possible**, (Rough Idea..)

The exact method I don't know, but you can make a Hack.. By using methods

`public int getDuration()` and  `getCurrentPosition()` of 
[MedaiPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class.

**Basic Idea**, What to do is make a ProgressBar (for complete video duration) and now when you add marker to it just get the duration of that marker (using some mathematical formula). And now check for current Position of your Video file, If its your marker position then using condition stop your video ans start a new Activity..

(If I'm going wrong let me know)

Comment: Yes the idea seems to be right, similar to what I thought of, but the tech. I get the duration bit and position bit. I am stuck at how to add markers to the progress bar gui wise(dynamic times) and also how to start an activity over the video (a small window) which just pauses the video in the background. And once the view is closed, the video restarts

Comment: For adding markers now its your turn to play and to open Activity as a small window use Activity with Dialog theme or Dialog itself and when it close start Video again...

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks, let me try it and I'll get back

Comment: I havent made progress on the adding markers to the progress bar . I have no clue how to add a marker at say 2 minutes and 3 minutes , pause the video at that point and then display some text over the video, and when the user plays the video, the video continues from the markers. I have set up the progress bar, i know the durations where i need to put the markers, i know the duration of the video. But how do I achieve this ?

Comment: Hey! Sorry to bother you @user370305 but have you made any progress ? I am still kinda stuck and planning to just close it and pursue it later

Comment: Marking this answer as correct - most help I got, thanks! Will come back to it to update how I ended up doing it

Comment: @Slartibartfast - As m busy with some other stuff I didn't pay time for this. ASAP I will also look at this.